# I can´t play one sound with winsound, but I can play an other one with same code

Tags: python-3.x

I created a Program that creates a GUI with different buttons. Two of them are supposed to play a sound/music file (mp3) in a loop. For the one file it works, but when I try the other one, it just give the windows sound if something can´t open correctly in a loop. There is no error in the console.

I tried to rename the second file, because I thought it could be because of a number in the title, but it didn´t worked. Then I looked if the file can even be opened and played, which it can. It also isn´t because of a coding mistake, because both sounds have the same code-structure.

bgmusic1() works, the other one not:

```py
   def bgmusic1():
       PlaySound(None, SND_ASYNC)
       PlaySound("sounds/test.mp3", SND_LOOP | SND_ASYNC)
       print("hi")

   def bgmusic2():
       PlaySound(None, SND_ASYNC)
       PlaySound("sounds/test2.mp3", SND_LOOP | SND_ASYNC)
       print("hi")
```

Comment: Where did you get `PlaySound`? I can only find this on PyPi https://pypi.org/project/playsound/ and it doesn't look like it's the same one you're using. --- Nevermind, I found it in `winsound.Playsound`

Comment: If `bgmusic1` works, why don't you remove the `SND_FILENAME` flag from `bgmusic2`? Since it seems for your case it's working without needing to pass the `SND_FILENAME` flag

Comment: still doesnt work